# cordova-plugin-facebook4 Facebook login not opening on iOS

Tags: ios, angularjs, facebook, cordova, facebook-login

I have a problem with **cordova-plugin-facebook4** (https://github.com/jeduan/cordova-plugin-facebook4) on **iOS** devices. After following the installation procedure as indicated in the documentation ("iOS Guide") and configuring correctly the app in the Facebook Developer Console,
when I click on my Facebook login button **nothing happens**. The XCODE console outputs the following error:

`2019-02-15 17:22:58.678937+0100 HelloCordovaApp[59179:1228209] Logging in with CORDOVA ... 2019-02-15 17:22:58.692742+0100 HelloCordovaApp[59179:1228209] Checking login status: unknown 2019-02-15 17:22:58.692947+0100 HelloCordovaApp[59179:1228209] Performing Fb login ... 2019-02-15 17:22:58.693087+0100 HelloCordovaApp[59179:1228209] Starting login 2019-02-15 17:22:58.693271+0100 HelloCordovaApp[59179:1228209] *** WebKit discarded an uncaught exception in the webView:decidePolicyForNavigationAction:request:frame:decisionListener: delegate: <NSInvalidArgumentException> Permissions should each be specified in separate string values in the array. 2019-02-15 17:22:58.694627+0100 HelloCordovaApp[59179:1228209] Client application failed to make a policy decision via WebPolicyDecisionListener, using defaultPolicy 2`

The app I developed is written in AngularJs and it's wrapped using Cordova.
What could it be? On **Android** devices it works perfectly...
Here's the code that's executed when user clicks on my Facebook login button:

```
function fbLoginButtonClick(){
    console.log('Logging in with CORDOVA ...');
    facebookConnectPlugin.getLoginStatus(_fbLoginStatusSuccess, _fbLoginStatusError);
}

////////

function _fbLoginStatusSuccess(response) {
    var responseStatus = response.status;
    console.log('Checking login status: ', responseStatus);
    if (responseStatus === 'connected') {
      _fbLoginSuccess();
    } else if (responseStatus !== null) {
      _doFbLogin();
    } else {
      handleFacebookError(responseStatus);
    }
 }

function _fbLoginStatusError(error) {
    handleFacebookError(error);
}   

function _doFbLogin() {
    console.log('Performing Fb login ...');
    facebookConnectPlugin.login(['email, public_profile'], _fbLoginSuccess, _fbLoginError);
}

function _fbLoginSuccess(result) {
    console.log('Fb API: getting user data ...');
    facebookConnectPlugin.api('/me?fields=id,name,first_name,last_name,email', ['email', 'public_profile'], _fbApiSuccess, _fbApiError);
}

function _fbLoginError(error) {
    handleFacebookError(error);
}  

function _fbApiSuccess(userData) {
    alert('User Authenticated!!');
    //redirect to admin page
}

function _fbApiError(error) {
    handleFacebookError(error);
}

function handleFacebookError (error) {
  if(error){
    console.log(error);
  }
}
```

And this is the configuration on my config.xml file:

```
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-facebook4" spec="4.2.1">
    <variable name="APP_ID" value="************" />
    <variable name="APP_NAME" value="HelloCordovaApp" />
    <variable name="FACEBOOK_HYBRID_APP_EVENTS" value="false" />
    <variable name="FACEBOOK_ANDROID_SDK_VERSION" value="4.40.0" />
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It took me a while to figure this out, basically the error is that the permissions you are passing to the SDK are in the wrong type. Here is how to fix this:

Replace this line:

```
facebookConnectPlugin.login(['email, public_profile'], _fbLoginSuccess, _fbLoginError);
```

With:

```
var perms = new Array("email","public_profile");
facebookConnectPlugin.login(perms, _fbLoginSuccess, _fbLoginError);
```

This should fix the problem for you. Good luck!